# Express req.body is empty. Is this the best way to be doing this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to express and trying to implement a basic login functionality but I'm a little confused with passing the data around. I have a couple of areas which seem to be confusing me.

1. I am storing the input value in a  `$scope.formdata` object which posts to /login. Is there a way I can access this object in my express backend.
2. I'm not quite sure why the req.body is undefined in this piece of code.

   ```
   app.get('/success', function(req, res){
   //console.log(req.body);
   res.json(req.user);
   ```

   });

Here's the express backend and angular code as follows:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport){

//index page - main login page
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
}));


app.get('/success', function(req, res){
    //console.log(req.body);
    res.json(req.user);
});

app.get('/failure', function(req, res){
    res.send('Failed');
});
```

};

```
    $scope.login = function(){
    $http.post('/login', $scope.formdata)
    .success(function (data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function (data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Upon successful login, I just want to redirect to a new page and display "hello, username"

Comment: if our $http request is post then you should look for req.body in app.post instead of app.get

Comment: the request object should be passed from the post /login state to the /success get state right?

Comment: Sorry i am unable to understand

Comment: Can you provide a solution to this? I tried what you suggested. It has to be a get method.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a body-parsing middleware, otherwise your `req.body` object will be `undefined`.

Example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); 

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
})
```

Documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body

Comment: It is still empty. req.body is empty, but res contains a user object but is undefined if i do res.user. why is this?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, passport will not pass the `req.body` object to the `/success` route. This route will be called upon successful authentication, it won't pass the original request body to it. As from passport's [documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure), upon calling this function you will have access to the `req.user` object, but not the `req.body` you originally posted. There is also no reason to: at this point, you should have a deserialised user object in `req.user`

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

Comment: Ok thank you for that, is it possible/best practice to control redirection from angular side? Isn't that the best way of achieving this so that the new page can contain hello, username.

Comment: @TarangHirani you can do the "user mr. X" on the successs redirect itself, assuming your deserialised user object contains that information. Remember, upon calling /success, you can access `req.user` object to get this information. Alternatively, you should probably be using this in combination with express-session middleware to preserve this information across your app once the user is authenticated.

Comment: Alright. thanks for this. I'm a little confused on the difference between the req and res objects in the /success url. Where are they coming from? Could u give me some insight into this? Why are they different in this case?

Comment: @TarangHirani I would recommend that you pay careful attention to the documentation of passport (the link I pasted in my original answer). The documentation is very good and extensive.

Comment: I did go through the entire documentation. I'm trying to understand where the requests, response objects are coming from. Trying to understand the data flow from front end to back end. Let me know if you some of some resources that could help out.